# In linux program cannot erase utf-8 character completely using backspace

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have a C program which waits for user's input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I run it and input some Chinese characters like `测试测试`. Then now I click backspace, I found I cannot erase these characters completely(some blank remained)

I found `termios` has a flag setting `IUTF8`, but why it doesn't work?

---

UPDATE ON 2022/12/31:

I am trying to describe my question more detailed, I have a program like this

[image: png1]

Now I run it and enter some Chinese characters(without Enter key)

[image: png2]

Then I keep clicking Backspace key(until nothing can be erased any more), but half of the content still display on my screen. It's so abnormal, how can I make the erase perform well?

[image: png3]

I know it is a stupid question for you. I just want to make it more comfortable when typing some UTF8 characters(like Chinese characters).

I found the shell can handle this well, how can I do to make my program perform the same?

By the way, this is my locale output

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Can reproduce on Xubuntu 22.04. Interestingly, this only happens in C/C++ programs, not in the shell itself.

Comment: UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding. If you wish to “delete” it then you must determine how many bytes one character is then delete that many.

Comment: @SafelyFast How can I make the "erase" operation perform correctly like the shell? I just want to make the input perform like a shell

Comment: Your question is unclear such that I cannot give you more of an answer than: determine how many bytes wide a specific character is (assume all input is UTF-8) and delete that many bytes. I don’t know your implementation details and that will be up for you to figure out.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the vscode terminal. Run your compiled program in a different terminal (e.g. xterm).

Comment: @YakovGalka no, I tryed it in many terminals, it displays the same. You can test it on yours

Comment: @Markity I did; i can erase the whole thing no problem; with either xterm and st.

Comment: I can reproduce in konsole 22.12.0 with `测试测试` characters. Other utf-8 characters work. For example `试` character, only "half" of the character is erased in terminal. This is most probably related to display wide characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) to provide a shell-like interface, with <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletion, correct input handling, et cetera.

To compile the following example program, make sure you have the `libreadline-dev` package installed.  The readline library needed to run the program will already be installed, because so many applications that are installed by default require it already.

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
// Compile using
//    gcc -Wall -O2 $(pkg-config --cflags readline) example.c $(pkg-config --libs readline) -o example

#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    while (1) {
        line = readline(NULL);  // No prompt

        // Input line is in 'line'; exit if end of input or empty line.
        if (!line || *line == '\0')
            break;

        // Do something with 'line'

        // Discard the dynamically allocated line
        free(line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When using the GNU readline library, the library takes over the standard input, and handles character deletion (and many other things) at the terminal (termios) level.  It works absolutely fine with file and pipe inputs as well, and is what e.g. `bash` shell uses for interactive input.